# Dymola error message when translating: "unknown internal error in Dymola"

Tags: modelica, dymola

I have problems translating Modelica models with Dymola 2020: When I try to translate the models, the following error message appears:

> "unknown internal error in Dymola".

The model was translating and simulating a couple of days ago, and the same model still runs on the computer of other colleagues. I didn't change the compiler in between nor the Dymola version. I've also restarted the computer but the problem persists.

Also, other models are still translating, so not all models are affected by this error.

Does anyone have a clue how to debug this error? Thank you very much for all hints!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most likely explanation would be some weird setting of some flag.
You can see if you have any odd settings of normal flags by:

- Dymola 2020: Edit>Options>General>Flags... Check "Non-default"
- Dymola 2020x: Tools>Options>General>Flags... Check "Non-default"

(If it is a non-Boolean setting it is a bit messier.)

That is assuming it is really the same model and there is no difference in any model in the path (including working directory).

Comment: Oh, and as @Dag stated - you should report it to technical support at Dassault Systèmes (through your reseller); including the name of that flag that caused the problem.

Comment: @HansOlsson, is there a document for showing the function of each flag?

Answer (score 5):

Frankly speaking, if you get "unknown internal error in Dymola" you should report it to technical support at Dassault Systèmes (through your reseller), and let them debug it.

It is not your job to debug such errors.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to delete the content from the working directory (WD)? 
Sometimes there are artifacts, which mess up the compilation of a specific model.

You can check where it is, using the

1. GUI, File -> Working Directory -> Copy Path and paste it in the Explorer
2. Command line typing `cd`, which returns the path to the WD

Then make sure that there are no important files in the WD (usually .mo files) and finally delete the full content of the directory.

Note: You should ensure that the WD is a local path (otherwise performance can take a serious hit). Besides that it is usually a good idea to have the WD separated form the directory where models are stored.

Comment: Yes, I've also cleared the complete working directory (which is indeed a local path and not on any network drive). Unfortunately this did not solve the problem.